# Resize Columns jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table, window-resize

I need assistance to get the resize to work in my example.

When the 'else' fires because of the resize, i want the columns to no longer get equalHeight so the columns snap back/fourth as the browser is resized. Basically the opposite to occur.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5N42p/10/show

All Code: http://jsfiddle.net/5N42p/10/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ( $(window).width() > 600 ) {
        $('.column').equalHeight(1);
    } else if ( $(window).width() ) {
        //what goes here?
    }
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    if ( $(window).width() > 600 ) {
        $('.column').equalHeight(1);
    } else if ( $(window).width() ) {
        //what goes here?
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.column').css("height","auto");
```

From Here:
http://www.cssnewbie.com/example_files/equal-heights/plugin.html

He has a Reset Blocks options that is using this code to remove the equal heights call.

Comment: thank you. i didn't think of that. Very grateful of your time.